# how to get a clean decoded param value

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want a decoded value from a query parameter, here is my code and check the data I am recieveing

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users/checkEmail")
public
@ResponseBody
boolean
verifyEmail(@RequestParam String emailAddress) {

    //in emailAddress I am getting value (emailAddress=mytestemail%40gmail.com)
    User User = userService.getUserByLoginName(emailAddress);

    return User != null;

}
```

here is the js code

```
$('#create-user-form').validate({
        rules: {
            emailAddress: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: '/MYCode/system/users/checkEmail',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'emailAddress': function() {
                            return $("input#emailAddress").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

I want to get the value mytest@gmail.com (i.e. without emailAddress= and %40)

Comment: Can we see what your request looks like?

Comment: The servlet API decodes parameters for you. The problem is on the client side. Show us the request.

Comment: client side code added, please check

Comment: I don't know Javascript. Can you open your browser network console and actually check the body of the request and post it here? It's extremely weird to me that you would receive the full `emailAddress=mytestemail%40gmail.com` as the value for a `@RequestParam`. I might understand `mytestemail%40gmail.com`, but not the `...=` part.

Comment: Please share a example request with all headers for further analysis.

I'm speculating but it sounds like you may have misconfigured spring mvc. [StringMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/converter/StringMessageConverter.html) is capable of what you are describing here. StringMessageConverter and other converters gets registered with spring on startup. Maybe you have messed up the configuration?